# How to pass function argument name as a string variable

Tags: python

I have a function with multiple arguments. I would like to pass data to the argument, depending on value in my variable. How to do this?

```
def Task(firstArg = None, lastArg = None):
    if firstArg is not None: do_something()
    if lastArg is not None: do_something_else()

arg = 'lastArg'
Task( arg = "Susanta")   # Expecting do_something_else()

arg = 'firstArg'
Task( arg = "Susanta")   # Expecting do_something()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    Task( arg = "Susanta")   # Expecting do_something_else()
TypeError: Task() got an unexpected keyword argument 'arg'
```

Comment: Look into python's `kwargs`. You can make a dict to represent the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it in as a dictionary that you unpack

```
Task(**{arg: "Susanta"})
```